# Right way to use mysqli_stmt... with an array

Tags: php, mysqli

I have an array with thousands of elements. Is this the right way to get it into the database:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($url, $usr, $pwd, $db) or die('<br><br>Error: ' . mysqli_error() . "<br><br>");
$stmt=mysqli_stmt_init($connection);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,"INSERT INTO Bible_KJV (verse) VALUES(?)");


$out .= "<br><hr><br>";
//Inserting the book in the database
for($i = 0;$i < count($lines);$i++) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$lines[$i]);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $versenr = $i+1;
    $out .= "Verse nr.: $versenr was inserted <br>";
}
```

Comment: I am a bit unsure if there is a better way than to call this mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$lines[$i]) for every element?

Comment: I believe that is the right way to use a prepared query (define it once, re-use it for speed purposes), but I am by no means a guru on that subject.

Comment: `$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, 'query here')` is all you really need. don't have to init a statement and prepare in two steps.

Answer (score 1):

There's also a bulk insert solution. Provided that php and MySQL share the same filesystem, you could do something like:

```
$filename=.... /* insert a temp filename here */
$connection = mysqli_connect($url, $usr, $pwd, $db) or die('<br><br>Error: ' . mysqli_error() . "<br><br>");
file_put_contents($filename,implode('\n',$lines));
mysqli_query($connection,"LOAD DATA INFILE '$filename' INTO TABLE `Bible_KJV`");
unlink($filename); // cleanup
```

Comment: Actually I got the $lines array from a file with \n as a seperator in the first place:) Thanks for the good suggestion! Good to know about this! Will see what I'll use!